# Java 11: for each loop con HashMap

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap, java-11

Estoy intentando iterar un HashMap en Java 11 pero el IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) me avisa que se requiere un **Object** y se encontro un **Entry**.
En este programa de java que escribí para demostrar el error no aparece ningún error, pero en el programa original sí aparece.
Código para la línea que contenía el error original y la línea de prueba sin error:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //HashMap original con error
        HashMap studentsGrade = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        studentsGrade.put("Manolo", 0.0);
        studentsGrade.put("Mafalda", 8.50);

        //HashMap de prueba sin error
       HashMap<String, Integer> mapPrueba = new HashMap<>();
       mapPrueba.put("Ejemplo", 1);
       mapPrueba.put("Ejemplo 2", 2);

        //Loop con error
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry:
              studentsGrade.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Prueba de linea original");
        }

        //Loop sin error
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry:
             mapPrueba.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("HashMap sin error");
        }

        /*
        Como indico el usuario de Stack Overflow Es Enrique Guadalupe Mote Rodrgue,
         el error esta en la linea 6 ya que no se declaro los valores que iba a tomar el HashMap antes de construir el
         HashMap.
         Para que el programa funcione:
         hay que reemplazar en la linea 6 "HashMap studentsGrade" por "HashMap<String, Double> studentsGrade"
         */
    }
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de iterar un HashMap en Java 11 en este caso? o ¿Qué cambia en el código original para que aparezca este error mientras que en el código de ejemplo no aparece?

Comment: Ese código funciona perfectamente en java 11. ¿Podrías compartir la traza completa?

Comment: No me había dado cuenta que este ejemplo no daba error. Acá esta el código original en el que encontré el error: https://pastebin.com/23U9qbfY.

Comment: el código que te genera error debe ir en la pregunta, edita y ahí colócalo

Comment: Agrega el código problemático aquí, para explicarte lo que ocurre.

Comment: El codigo debe ir en la pregunta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viendo el código que compartes, me parece que el error se debe a que en el código que tu subes (prueba sin error) estas declarando el tipo de dato Key y Value para el HashMap, mientras que en el segundo código (prueba con error) no lo haces.

```
//Esto es correcto, al declarar el tipo K, y V del HashMap
HashMap<String, Double> mapPrueba = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

```
/*Declarar el HashMap de esta forma no causa error, sin embargo hace que el 
metodo entrySet retorne un Set en lugar del Set<Entry>*/
HashMap studentsGrades = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

El no declarar los tipos `K`, y `V` del Map puede causar otros errores como `Unchecked call to...`

Comment: En efecto ese era el error! Nunca me hubiese dado cuenta de que eso era lo que causaba el error solo...